# switchMap with array of Observables

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs

I'm trying Rxjs 5 to simplify some Node.js nested callbacks. I need to read a directory (fs.readdir), then read stats of each file (fs.stats) and parse them if they were modified since last sync.

The following code works but I find it a bit odd and not "the rxjs way" because of the first switchMap which is too big!

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { Observable } = require('rxjs');

const lastSync = new Date(2017, 01, 01);
const pathToFolder = '/any/path/';

Observable.bindNodeCallback(fs.readdir)(pathToFolder)
  .switchMap((files) => {
    const array = files.map((fileName) => {
      return Observable.zip(
        Observable.of(fileName),
        Observable.bindNodeCallback(fs.stat)(path.join(pathToFolder, fileName))
      );
    });
    return Observable.concat(...array);
  })
  .filter(([fileName, stats]) => stats.mtime.getTime() > lastSync.getTime())
  .subscribe(([fileName, stats]) => parseFile(fileName));

function parseFile(fileName) { /* ... */ }
```

How can I improve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest that the `switchMap` operator be replaced with `mergeMap`. Only a single array of files (or an error) is going to be emitted from the bound callback, so it will never be necessary to switch; a merge is all that's required.

And the `Observable.zip` call could be simplified. You could use a `map` operator to pair the file name and the stats.

```ts
Observable.bindNodeCallback(fs.readdir)(pathToFolder)
  .mergeMap((files) => {
    const array = files.map((fileName) => Observable
      .bindNodeCallback(fs.stat)(path.join(pathToFolder, fileName))
      .map((stats) => [fileName, stats])
    );
    return Observable.concat(...array);
  })
  .filter(([fileName, stats]) => stats.mtime.getTime() > lastSync.getTime())
  .subscribe(([fileName, stats]) => parseFile(fileName));
```

It's possible to further simplify the composed observable by taking advantage of the fact that the operators in the `concact` and `merge` families also support arrays. So, [`concatAll`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatAll) can be used to flatten the array, emitting the file names from the `readdir` callback. And those file names can then be mapped to stats with a `concatMap` operator:

```ts
Observable.bindNodeCallback(fs.readdir)(pathToFolder)
  .concatAll()
  .concatMap((fileName) => Observable
    .bindNodeCallback(fs.stat)(path.join(pathToFolder, fileName))
    .map((stats) => [fileName, stats])
  )
  .filter(([fileName, stats]) => stats.mtime.getTime() > lastSync.getTime())
  .subscribe(([fileName, stats]) => parseFile(fileName));
```

Comment: FYI, it's possible to simplify further. (I toyed briefly with this yesterday, but TypeScript was not playing nice with my simple array-based repro. Had a closer look this morning to get it sorted.)